# How much is car tax in France?

Tags: taxes, france, car-insurance

I moved to France and brought my car (2009, 5 cv) from other EU country.

I pay a lot for my car insurance (about 140 euro per month) so I want to quite that and get a French insurance. But to get a cheap french insurance (which can be as low as 35 euro per month) most insurance companies require a French registration number (or 'plaque' as its called here), and it [costs](https://www.service-public.fr/simulateur/calcul/cout-certificat-immatriculation#main) about 220 euros for me.

So to decide whether it worth all the costs and paper works of getting a French plaque, I need to know the car's annual tax in France. Obviously if the tax is to high comparing with my home country I would not bother to get a french plaque.

But I could not find any info for the car tax rates. So appreciate if you could tell me roughly how much annual car tax should I expect or refer me to an online simulator for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have your "carte grise" and your physical numberplate on the car, it's all good for you.

You have nothing to pay annually except your car insurance of course

Road tax has been abolished in France in 2001.

Comment: Very interesting! Can you name some of the best budget insurance companies please?

Comment: You will also have to take care of the contrôle technique https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2878